# why does my insert sql query always return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, coffeescript

why does this sql-query always return the row as **undefined**??

CoffeeScript:

```
data.get "insert into users (name, password)
values ('#{user.name}', '#{user.password}')", (err, row) ->
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.get is for queries, not for inserts. What is happening is that the statement returns an error.

See this for a tutorial on how to insert tuples:

[Intro to Coffee Script and SQLite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/coffeescript/coffeescript_sqlite.htm)

Comment: I want to insert data and at the same time select all the fields of the inserted data. !!! do you have a line of code for me ?

Comment: okay... I did it. simply put another get (select) statement as callback !! thanks.